# Coveo for Sitecore issue with SearchBox and SearchView with OmniboxResultView

Tags: coveo

I am using a `Search box` with suggestions and 4 `OmniboxResults` view (each with filter expression to group different results) on all pages. It internally uses `Coveo Search View Resources` and `Search Box View`. Works fine on all pages, I can query and it does show suggestions + 4 different results per `OmniboxResults` view.

But on Search Results page which also has `Coveo Search View Resources` and `Search View`, it only displays query results with 1st `OmniboxResults` view (no matter which one is set).

Is this expected or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In general, you shouldn't use the the Results Suggestion feature of the search box when you are on the search page. This is because it's the job of the search page to display the results. With Results Suggestions, you are duplicating the results list and this is confusing for the visitors.

I suggest you to disable the OmniBox Result List components when you are on the search page. You can hide them with Sitecore personalization and the "hide component" option if you are using an Enterprise Edition of Coveo for Sitecore. They can be removed directly in the Presentation Details too.

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way to make them not conflict?

Comment: I haven't tried your setup so I'm not sure if the conflict is normal or not.